# como activar o descativar esta funcion en leaflet (js)

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones, leaflet

lo que trato de hacer es que un botón al ser clikeado active la función "X" hasta ahi no tengo problema, lo que si quiero que haga pero no lo hace es que al volver a ser activado desactive la función nuevamente. para que entiendan mas de lo que hablo dejen les muestro el codigo:

```
        <p>
        <input type="button" value="ruta vista imss"   onclick="rutavistaimss()" >
        </p> 
<script>
        var rutavs = 
        { 
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "ruta vista imss"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": rutavistaimsscoords
            }
        };
    var myStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
    };


    function rutavistaimssA(){
        L.geoJSON(rutavs, {
        style: myStyle
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea un flag:

```js
let flag = true

function myFunction() {
  if (flag) {
    // your logic
    console.log('im active')
  }
  flag = !flag
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```